# AWS Encryption in React Native

Tags: react-native, encryption, amazon-kms

I am in the middle of developing an app in React Native. What I am going to do is to encrypt Token coming from the third party using AWS Encryption and send encrypted Token to the server using the HTTP POST method.

Given details for encryption are KeyID, Access Key, and Secret Key.

**KeyID: ARN: arn:aws:kms:us-west-1:188480393...:key/8rda...

aws_access_key_id: AKIA...

aws_secret_access_key: 17qKv...**

I've tested the encryption process using AWS Encryption SDK CLI and it worked well. But I am not sure how to get started encryption with the above details in React Native.
Could someone recommend me any good example?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at the aws-encryption-sdk-javascript [browser example code](https://github.com/aws/aws-encryption-sdk-javascript/tree/master/modules/example-browser)?

Answer (score 0):

The browser example produces lots of error for me, like there is no crypto module in react native, which causes it to crash with client-browser package.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use aws-kms sdk inside react-native app as it supports react-native. It will be very similar to how you use it in your backend.

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';

// Create a new KMS client
const kms = new AWS.KMS();

// Encrypted text to decrypt
const encryptedText = 'ENCRYPTED_TEXT';

// Decrypt the text
kms.decrypt({ CiphertextBlob: Buffer.from(encryptedText, 'base64') }, (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log(data.Plaintext.toString('utf8'));
  }
});
```

You can find more this [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/getting-started-react-native.html#getting-started-react-write-native-code)